# deploy to GAE flexible environment stuck forever?

Tags: google-app-engine

I try to deploy a simple `nodejs` app to `GAE` flexible environment.
Followed [the official guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart), using this command:

`gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug`

I tried a lot of times.

The logs give me these forever:

```
DEBUG: Operation [apps/just-aloe-212502/operations/b1e812f6-299c-438e-b335-e35aa343242a] not complete. Waiting to retry.
Updating service [flex-env-get-started] (this may take several minutes)...⠛DEBUG: Operation [apps/just-aloe-212502/operations/b1e812f6-299c-438e-b335-e35aa343242a] not complete. Waiting to retry.
Updating service [flex-env-get-started] (this may take several minutes)...⠛DEBUG: Operation [apps/just-aloe-212502/operations/b1e812f6-299c-438e-b335-e35aa343242a] not complete. Waiting to retry.
Updating service [flex-env-get-started] (this may take several minutes)...⠹DEBUG: Operation [apps/just-aloe-212502/operations/b1e812f6-299c-438e-b335-e35aa343242a] not complete. Waiting to retry.
Updating service [flex-env-get-started] (this may take several minutes)...⠼DEBUG: Operation [apps/just-aloe-212502/operations/b1e812f6-299c-438e-b335-e35aa343242a] not complete. Waiting to retry.
```

What happened?

I can run my simple nodejs `hello-world` app successfully in local. And, the `GAE` standard environment works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should note that App Engine Flexible environment is [based on Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/), so it takes time to configure the infrastructure when you deploy your app.

The first deployment of a new version of an App Engine Flexible application takes some time due to setting up of internal infrastructure however subsequent deployments should be relatively fast since it only modifies some GCP resources and then waits on the health checks.

Deployment requires docker image building (which you can skip if you already have a pre-built image uploaded to gcr.io). Using a [pre-build (to gcr.io) docker image](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/testing-and-deploying-your-app#remote-container-build) will skip docker build step and would optimize the deployment time.

Comment: Yeah. I know it. But, can you believe the deployment take me a whole night?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue by following the quickstart you mentioned, but it works fine for me and the app gets deployed successfully. So,  I recommend to double check ["Before you begin"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart#before-you-begin) steps and if the issue persists, you may report it to the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#bug_reports) and provide us with the REDACTED output of the "gcloud app deploy --verbosity debug" and "gcloud info --anonymize" so that we would be able to dig into the issue.

Comment: thanks. I am doubt about it's my network issue. I will give a try at home using my personal network and computer. But it's weird that GAE standard environment works fine. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please take note that If you are behind a corporate proxy or firewall, you should [configure your Cloud SDK for use behind a proxy/firewall](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings).